# Upload specific or all tables from Geopackage to PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I would like to upload a specific table (i.e. `U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1 (Multi Polygon)`) from a Geopackage file to a PostGIS database from the command line. I tried:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:database" \
    -t_srs EPSG:3035 -overwrite -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nln "corine.corine12_vec" \
    U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg
```

However, I just realized, the Geopackage contains multiple tables and only (the wrong) one (i.e. `U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_MYT (Multi Polygon)`) is uploaded.

**Q: How can I upload a specific table or all tables?**

Output of `ogrinfo U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg`:

```
INFO: Open of `U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1 (Multi Polygon)
2: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_REU (Multi Polygon)
3: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_GLP (Multi Polygon)
4: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_GUF (Multi Polygon)
5: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_MTQ (Multi Polygon)
6: U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1_FR_MYT (Multi Polygon)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the name of the tale inside a Geopackage:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:database" -t_srs EPSG:3035 -overwrite -lco \
    GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nln "corine.corine12_vec" \
    U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg NAME_OF_LAYER
```

So for example for the `U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1 layer`:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:database" -t_srs EPSG:3035 -overwrite -lco \
    GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nln "corine.corine12_vec" \
    U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1
```

For all tables if you do not need to rename the layers (from @user30184 in the comments), you can run:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:database" -t_srs EPSG:3035 -overwrite \
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco SCHEMA=corine U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg
```

This will use the layer name from the Geopackage, and uses the `-lco SCHEMA=`  tag for specifying a schema.

Comment: Single command is enough for all tables if there is no need to rename the tables. `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:database" -t_srs EPSG:3035 -overwrite -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom     U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1.gpkg"` should convert everything.

Comment: @user30184 thanks, I updated the answer.